# Updating 2 models at once with same attributes in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-models

i hav this in my store_opening_stock form

```
    <%= simple_form_for @store_opening_stock do |f| %>
      <%= f.error_messages %>
      <p>
      <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>

      <%= f.label :employee_id %>
      <%= f.collection_select :employee_id, Employee.all, :id, :name, options ={:prompt => "-Select  employee  Name"}, :class => "employee name", :style=>'width:210px;'%><br />

         <%= f.label :date %>
        <%= f.datepicker :date, :dateFormat => 'dd MM, yy',  :showOn => "both", :buttonImage => "/assets/calendar.gif", :buttonImageOnly => true, :changeMonth => true, :changeYear => true, :placeholder => "Click on the calender", :yearRange =>'1950:2042' %><br/>

        <%= f.label :product_id %>
        <%= f.collection_select :product_id, Product.all, :id, :title, options ={:prompt => "-Select  Product  Name"}, :class => "product name", :style=>'width:210px;'%><br /> 

        <%= f.input :batch_no,  :label => 'Batch No', :input_html => { :size => 30}%><br/>
        <%= f.input :price,  :label => 'price', :input_html => { :size => 30}, :placeholder =>'Enter Digits'%><br/> 
        <%= f.input :quantity,  :label => 'quantity', :input_html => { :size => 30}, :placeholder =>'Enter Digits'%><br/>
       <p><%= f.submit %></p>
<% end %>
```

And i have 2 models, one is store_opening_stock.rb and stock.rb

```
class StoreOpeningStock < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :comments_attributes, :stocks_attributes
  attr_accessible :user_id, :date ,:store_location_id, :product_id, :batch_no
  attr_accessible :expiry_date, :price, :quantity, :comment_id, :employee_id
  attr_accessible :goods_receipt_id

  has_many :stocks    
end


class Stock < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :date, :store_location_id, :product_id, :batch_no, :expiry_date, :price, :quantity, :goods_reciept_id

    belongs_to :store_opening_stock, :foriegn_key => "store_opening_stock_id"
    acts_as_store_opening_stock
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :store_opening_stocks
end
end
```

Is there a way i can update PRICE, PRODUCT_ID, QUANTITY, BATCH-NO from store_opening_stocks to stock as soon as i click submit in store_opening_stock form????? Can i update 2 tables at once as i press submit in Ruby on rails????
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. See you are already using 'accepts_nested_attributes_for' in stock.rb model which is a nice practice while saving multiple 'store_opening_stock' records from a stock model form.

But if you want to have different model attributes in form, you can do this by using [fields_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for)

Comment: Nimesh i m a little confused. sorry I m new to the framework, how exactly field's for will help me updating say `price` in both the tables at the same time with one form????

Comment: Please refer above link of 'fields_for' docs and scroll down to 'One-to-many' section which is a most similar to your requirement. Once you insert price input fields of 'stock' model in your form, they will be automatically created when saving store_opening_stock in your db

Comment: went through, Thanks alot Nimesh.